# Disable ableplayer keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable [Able player](https://github.com/ableplayer) keyboard shortcut. i would appreciate any help anyone could provide

Comment: We aren't here to do work for you, we're here to help you solve a problem after you already tried to your best ability. So. What have you tried?

Comment: you already ask  this question on https://github.com/ableplayer/ableplayer/issues/259

Comment: yes i asked but don't get any help. Secondly i think on stackoverflow you can get help faster.If you still think the question should not be here i will remove